# Vue Plugin Error: VueVirtualScroller is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My issue is that im trying to make use of this VueVirtualScroller plugin, but I keep getting an error saying that its not defined. 
Uncaught ReferenceError: VueVirtualScroller is not defined

I feel like im just missing some step to make use of the plugin. I even tried using npm rather than a script tag, but it had the same result.

Here is my use code that is placed in my main app.js file

```
Vue.use(VueVirtualScroller);
```

And the script tag im using to load VueVirtualScroller

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-virtual-scroller@1.0.0-beta.4/dist/vue-virtual-scroller.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How are you building your project? are you using npm? or just script tags?

Comment: You need to import it. I think this plugin will only work with npm.

Comment: I tried it with both npm and script tags, but they both led to the same error message

Comment: Did you include css `vue-virtual-scroller.css`?